# How to implement Single Sign-in in django?

Tags: angularjs, django

I have two web sites.

After login in one website we are redirecting him to the second web site,but he needs to login again in second website

How can i bypass the login in second web site? I'm using angular js

Comment: your question is unclear, are you looking for single sign in?

Comment: Yes ,single sign in

Comment: use django same package

Comment: We are using django only for backend. and maintaining front-end in different repositories

Answer (score 1):

The most safe solution is probably to pass just a token which, when POST called to backend would also authenticate user on the second page.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you explain more about this solution

Comment: It is almost impossible, since we don't know your backend implementation of the auth service or the way it works. And of course, how the redirect is proccesed. Try providing more info.

Comment: from backend we will only redirect him to the url. in the request token will come.

Comment: So on the backend, generate token, pass it in the url, and in the controller that handles the state that is going to be display just process $stateParams for example. After that, just use the token to call the backend auth URL. Don't forget to check the validity of the token on the backend afterwards.